# condición para revisar si una lista es mayor a 2 en haskell

Tags: haskell

tengo esta lista llamada traducción que me va a contener o uno o varios elementos pero quiero hacer algo si mi lista es mayor a 2 y otra cosa si es menor pero al colocarla así

```
if (length traducción > 2) then do
            nuevalistaplaneta <- return (ignorar planetas traducción)
```

me dice que el error proviene del do, pero si quito el do no puedo hacer la asignación de abajo entonces no se como podría estructurar la condición

Comment: Aunque entiendo lo que pides, no sé para qué lo haces. Es como si estuvieras pensando hacer en haskell algo que sólo has pensado con otros lenguajes. Los *ifs* en haskell casi no tienen utilidad. Intenta transformar lo que estés intentando hacer en una función con salvaguardas (o inténta expresarlo como una función y te completo lo que falte).

Answer (score 0):

Como dice Chema Cortés Haskell tendría más sentido hacerlo con guardas y hacer en cada guarda lo que quieras hacer, pero aun con todo se puede hacer con condicionales si quieres.

```
funcion :: [a] -> "lo que quieras devolver"
funcion traduccion = if ((length traduccion)<2) then funcion1 traduccion   
                   else funcion2 traduccion
```